# Phone calls from sons phone showing up on my phone

Tags: iphone

How do I stop my sons phone calls from showing up on my phone?

Comment: Are you sharing an Apple ID?

Comment: Many seem to assume they will have better control or save money on purchases by sharing appleids... Truth is appleids are not meant to be shared, everyone should have there own, then you can use "family sharing" and "parental controls"

Comment: Unfortunately, "family sharing" doesn't work for everything.  My wife and I share an Apple ID so that we can have the same contacts and the same iCloud where our accounting data is sync'd

Answer (score 2):

You may [create a different Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/account) for your son (or for you), or disable iPhone Cellular Calls. Go to Settings > FaceTime and turn them off.

You can use Family Sharing –as suggested– to share purchased apps and media, among other things.

Answer (score -1):

You should look into Settings-Phone-and disable Calls on Other Devices.
That may work for you.